# Scala and HTML parsing

Tags: html, xhtml, scala

How do you load an HTML DOM document into Scala? The XML singleton had errors when trying to load the xmlns tags.

```
import java.net._
import java.io._
import scala.xml._

object NetParse {

   import java.net.{URLConnection, URL}
   import scala.xml._

   def netParse(sUrl: String): Elem = {
       var url = new URL(sUrl)
       var connect = url.openConnection

       XML.load(connect.getInputStream)
   }
}
```

---

Finally I found a solution! - Requires scala 2.7.7 or higher to work (2.7.0 has a fatal bug):
[How-to-use-TagSoup-with-Scala-XML](http://old.nabble.com/How-to-use-TagSoup-with-Scala-XML--td17575225.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This may help you
[Processing real world HTML as if it were XML in scala](http://www.hars.de/2009/01/html-as-xml-in-scala.html)

Comment: Viewing that page today, most of the code examples are missing. Here's a link to a version that still has all the original content: http://web.archive.org/web/20111121010724/http://www.hars.de/2009/01/html-as-xml-in-scala.html

Comment: For those looking for a easy way to get this lib into your project see [http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2.1).

Answer (score 6):

Try using `scala.xml.parsing.XhtmlParser` instead.

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution will not work for "tag soup" -- only well-formed XHTML will parse successfully. So, basically it just adds standard HTML entities and apparently preserves CDATA blocks, as compared to scala.xml.XML.load*. (In my case, this was all I needed though, so yeah!)

Answer (score 5):

I have just tried to use this answer with scala 2.8.1 and ended up using the work from:

http://www.hars.de/2009/01/html-as-xml-in-scala.html

The interesting bit that I needed was:

```
val parserFactory = new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.jaxp.SAXFactoryImpl
val parser = parserFactory.newSAXParser()
val source = new org.xml.sax.InputSource("http://www.scala-lang.org")
val adapter = new scala.xml.parsing.NoBindingFactoryAdapter
adapter.loadXML(source, parser)
```

Comment: This works for me too. However, I'd like to be able to convert raw HTML to an input source, so either in the `val source=` line or `adapter.loadXML` section. I've tried `adapter.loadString("<html>...")`, but it fails on malformed content. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

## Scala Scraper

I recommend [Scala Scraper](https://github.com/ruippeixotog/scala-scraper) that lets you parse HTML elegantly like this:

```
// Parse elements from files, URLs or plain strings
val browser = JsoupBrowser()
val doc = browser.parseFile("core/src/test/resources/example.html")
val doc2 = browser.get("http://example.com")
val doc3 = browser.parseString("<html><h1>parse me</h1></html>")

// Extract the text inside the element with id "header"
doc >> text("#header")

// Extract the <span> elements inside #menu
val items = doc >> elementList("#menu span")

// From each item, extract all the text inside their <a> elements
items.map(_ >> allText("a"))
```

Examples are taken from the Scala Scraper's [readme](https://github.com/ruippeixotog/scala-scraper/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 2):

```
/* 
Copyright (c) 2008 Florian Hars, BIK Aschpurwis+Behrens GmbH, Hamburg 
Copyright (c) 2002-2008 EPFL, Lausanne, unless otherwise specified. 
All rights reserved. 

This software was developed by the Programming Methods Laboratory of the 
Swiss Federal Institute of Technology (EPFL), Lausanne, Switzerland. 

Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in source 
or binary form for any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, 
provided that the following conditions are met: 

1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright 
  notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer. 

2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright 
  notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the 
  documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution. 

3. Neither the name of the EPFL nor the names of its contributors 
  may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this 
  software without specific prior written permission. 


 THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE REGENTS AND CONTRIBUTORS ``AS IS'' AND 
 ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE 
 IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE 
 ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE REGENTS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE 
 FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL 
 DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR 
 SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER 
 CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT 
 LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY 
 OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF 
 SUCH DAMAGE. 
*/ 

package tagsoup 

import org.xml.sax.InputSource 
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser 
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.jaxp.SAXFactoryImpl 
import scala.xml.parsing.FactoryAdapter 
import scala.xml._ 

class TagSoupFactoryAdapter extends FactoryAdapter { 

  val parserFactory = new SAXFactoryImpl 
  parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(false) 

  val emptyElements = Set("area", "base", "br", "col", "hr", "img", 
                      "input", "link", "meta", "param") 

  /** Tests if an XML element contains text. 
   * @return true if element named <code>localName</code> contains text. 
   */ 
  def nodeContainsText(localName: String) = !(emptyElements contains localName) 

  /** creates a node. 
  */ 
  def createNode(pre:String, label: String, attrs: MetaData, 
             scpe: NamespaceBinding, children: List[Node] ): Elem = { 
    Elem( pre, label, attrs, scpe, children:_* ); 
  } 

  /** creates a text node 
  */ 
  def createText( text:String ) = 
    Text( text ); 

  /** Ignore Processing Instructions 
  */ 
  def createProcInstr(target: String, data: String) = Nil 

  /** load XML document 
   * @param source 
   * @return a new XML document object 
   */ 
  override def loadXML(source: InputSource) = { 
    val parser: SAXParser = parserFactory.newSAXParser() 

    scopeStack.push(TopScope) 
    parser.parse(source, this) 
    scopeStack.pop 
    rootElem 
  } 

}
```

[How-to-use-TagSoup-with-Scala-XML](http://old.nabble.com/How-to-use-TagSoup-with-Scala-XML--td17575225.html)