# What is the shortest way in Scala/Java to grab all information from a website AND parse it for buttons(including ID and Class if present)?

Tags: java, scala, xml-parsing, selenium-webdriver

I need to grab the id's, classes, and any other information included in the tags.
I'm working in Scala, Java is fine though.
This is an exact match parser. It will only grab "button".
"button id=...", for example, is excluded.
Other parser? Make my own?
This is what I've found so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Currently(using Selenium WebDriver and Scala.XML):
// Opens Browser and goes to page
driver.get(URL)

// Gets XML/html/etc.. and converts it to XML format                                     
val xmlData = XML.loadString(driver.getPageSource)  

// Parse for buttons
(xmlData \ "button").text
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you count on only well-formed XML pages? 'Cause lots of sites / pages are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a "do my code for me" question and should be closed, but at least you have tryed something.

1) **Parsing**

You can't parse `html` direct to `xml`, since it's not a valid `xml`, you [should use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695902/scala-and-html-parsing) html parser. I prefer [Tag Soup](http://blog.dub.podval.org/2010/08/scala-and-tag-soup.html).

2) **Searching for button**

You should use method `\\` instead of `\` to search in all subelements.

3) **Geting attributes**

With `\\` or `\` method you'll get `NodeSeq`. You should iterate over it to parse `Node` objects.

```
for(node <- nodeSeq) yield ???
```

You could use method `text` to get text of element and method `\` do get attribute:

```
val id = (node \ "@id").text
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! I looked into Tag Soup prior and was considering it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you a [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library. It has a lot of cool features and here are my top 3:

- Very easy to start with and use
- Can parse even broken/invalid HTML
- Gives you the power of CSS selectors (similar to JQuery)

Here is a small example:

```
val rows = (Jsoup connect "http://some.page.com/test.html" get) select 
  "h1:contains(Example Table Header) ~ table tr"

rows.toList drop 1 foreach { row =>
  println(row select "td:eq(1)" text)
}
```

This small snippet will download `test.html`, parse it and select all of the table rows  (except the header row) from the HTML, that matches following structure:

```
<h1>Example Table Header</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Some</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It will print:

```
Some
Test
```