# Traversing through HTM tags and extracting values would possible in Gatling?

Tags: html, css, regex, gatling

I'm looking for something which is built-in by `gatling` here in this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/WIGH_nYw-Mg

I want to know how many lists i.e. `<li> </li>`, tags rendered in the below `<ul class="product_list grid row">`? how would I find that 5 `<li>` items are rendered dynamically on page?

```
<ul class="product_list grid row">
 <li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 first-in-line first-item-of-tablet-line first-item-of-mobile-line" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;"></li>
 <li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 last-item-of-tablet-line" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;"></li>
 <li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 last-in-line first-item-of-tablet-line last-item-of-mobile-line" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;"></li>
 <li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 first-in-line last-line last-item-of-tablet-line first-item-of-mobile-line last-mobile-line"></li>
 <li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 last-line first-item-of-tablet-line last-mobile-line">
</ul>
```

2. Then, from each `<li>`, I want to extract `product_img_link` and  `product-price` values

`<li class="ajax_block_product col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 first-in-line first-item-of-tablet-line first-item-of-mobile-line" style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 0px;">
   <div class="product-container" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="left-block">
     <div class="product-image-container">
       <a class="product_img_link" href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=3&amp;controller=product" title="Printed Dress" itemprop="url">
        <img class="replace-2x img-responsive" src="http://automationpractice.com/img/p/8/8-home_default.jpg" alt="Printed Dress" title="Printed Dress" width="250" height="250"            itemprop="image"> </a>
        <div class="content_price" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <span itemprop="price" class="price product-price">
         $26.00 </span></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div> <!-- .product-container> -->
</li>`

I tried below `check` but didn't helped

```
.check(regex("""<ul class="product_list grid row"> (.*) <!-- .product-container> -->""").findAll.saveAs("""ul_list""")))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See [Scala and HTML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695902/scala-and-html-parsing). Do not use regex to parse HTML when there exist the *right* tools.