# Error tolerant XML reader

Tags: c#, .net, xml, rss

Does anyone have/make/sell an error tolerant XML reader for .NET?

Yeah, I know, XML isn't designed to have errors in it and should be rejected if it's not valid .. blah blah.  But sadly the real-world is imperfect and developers do make mistakes and I still want to be able to read their feeds even if I'm missing the odd element here or there because it wasn't encoded properly or had some other error in it.  **So please, no answers "fix the source" or "reject it".**

So, does anyone have a component that can recover and handle common mistakes in XML files?

Comment: Maybe you want an SGML parser? By definition, there's no such thing as "XML with errors", there's just "not quite XML".

Comment: Based on this logic (real world isn't perfect), someone should create a SQL query parser that understands broken and/or incorrect SQL. And someone should create a C# compiler that understand incorrect C# code...

Comment: Does anyone have/make/sell a car with no engine (not a missing engine)?  Unless you're the Flinstones, that doesn't make sense either.  Ok, so it can be done, but Steve makes an excellent point: `What would be the function specifications?`  Think HTML and all the different ways the browsers render invalid HTML (not to mention valid HTML).  When you're dealing with a data-transfer file spec, you won't have rendering problems but rather data corruption/loss.

Comment: *I DON'T CARE ABOUT DATA LOSS*, I want the elements that I can salvage from a 10,000 item RSS feed that has one bad character in one element.  Read the question!  Web browsers do a passable job rendering busted HTML all day long, that's good enough for this application.

Comment: Do you have specific cases in mind you'd like to handle?  Are you using a specific subset of XML that limits the possible cases you need to consider?  Do you have a known schema that you can use to try to 'repair' the data?

Comment: @Hightechrider: In that case an HTML parser would probably be the closest since it catches missing ending tags, etc.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511978/error-tolerant-xml-parsing-in-scala, http://infolab.stanford.edu/OntoAgents/xlint/index.html

Comment: Thanks @Nelson, xlint might work if current HtmlAgilityPack route fails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Parse malformed XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996552/c-parse-malformed-xml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look around HTML Parser, 'cause html is almost xml

Comment: OK, so the `HtmlAgilityPack` appears to be able to handle it, this is the CORRECT answer for the question posed.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack has issues, for example, it doesn't like <link> elements because they are self-closing in HTML.

Comment: A modified version of HtmlAgilityPack with the ability to not self-close tags link 'link' was able to parse the file recovering most of the records.

Answer (score 14):

It's precisely because the real world is imperfect that XML is so widely used.  What would be the functional specification for an error-tolerant XML parser?  It's an open-ended problem.  It's hard enough to parse all variations of well-formed XML without trying to second-guess all possible errors.

[... Waits for downvote.]

Comment: +1 vote from me. If the XML is 'broken', how can an automated process possibly make correct 'guesses' about the content in any but the most extremely simple errors? The results would be quite ugly, and might not come to light for a while, since no 'error' has occurred.

Comment: No, I don't think a downvote would be appropriate there. The OP's query is certainly valid but your point is very well made.

Answer (score 3):

Run the XML through [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) first. That will clean your XML of errors so it parses correctly

Comment: I had to laugh at the description "It yields a parse tree that makes approximately as much sense as your original document."

Comment: With data, it's always GIGO. But well-formed garbage is always better since at least you can load what you have. Many problems come from anomalies that the programs generating the XML don't handle. For most applications, it's better to normalize out a few entries than not be able to load anything.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific case of an RSS feed and the specific case of individual corrupt item entries, you can use [XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hh47ty4%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) to manually read in each item separately, handling the XmlException for invalid items.  When an Exception occurs, you'll need to use a new Reader instance, as the original Reader is hosed.  You'll still have to have valid `<item>` and `</item>` tags to identify each item, but you'll be able to recover from corrupt data within each item.

Answer (score 2):

yes, I know it's old question, but recently I was looking for tolerant xml parser and found the following: [XmlParser](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/XmlParser).

> A Roslyn-inspired full-fidelity XML parser with no dependencies and a
>   simple Visual Studio XML language service.
>
> The parser produces a full-fidelity syntax tree, meaning every
>   character of the source text is represented in the tree. The tree
>   covers the entire source text. The parser has no dependencies and can
>   easily be made portable.

You can add Nugets in your project. I tried this parser and it can read any XML files.