# C# XmlSerializer to serialize/deserialize special char

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlserializer

I find XmlSerializer cannot handle a char correctly when serialize/deserialize an object, sorry I cannot type it here, please see below image.

Does anybody know how to handle such a char when serialize/deserialize it?

Thanks a lot!

[image]
[image]

My code sample:
An entity class definition:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string value;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Entity.Value: {0}", this.value);
    }
}
```

Create an XmlSerializer object based on the entity type:

```
private XmlSerializer GetXmlSerializer()
{
    xmlSerializer = default(XmlSerializer);

    Type type = typeof(Entity);
    IEnumerable<Type> types = new List<Type> { type };

    xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(type, types.ToArray());

    return xmlSerializer;
}
```

Code to serialize an Entity object:

```
private void BT_Serialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, entity);
        string result = sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Code to deserialize an Entity object based on the XML serialized (I can change it manually):

```
private void BT_Deserialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        object obj = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);

        Entity entity = obj as Entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081425/error-tolerant-xml-reader

Comment: It handles the char correctly for xml 1.0, by not allowing it, even in its "escaped" form. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152666/292411

Comment: Thanks for you both.