# How to parse malformed XML into an XmlDocument without exceptions in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I am trying to parse the request body of an HTTP request into an `XmlDocument`, but I couldn't find any way to do so in a way that gracefully handles parsing failure. `LoadXml` just throws an exception if the XML is malformed.

Is there something *like* `TryLoadXml`?

```cs
using var stringReader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, true);
var body = await stringReader.ReadToEndAsync();

var requestXmlBody = new XmlDocument();
requestXmlBody.LoadXml(body); // Throws exception if Request.Body is malformed XML
```

What I would like to do:

```cs
var requestXmlBody = new XmlDocument();
if (requestXmlBody.TryLoadXml("<test<test/>")) // Fails to parse, skips code
{
    // Code here...
}
```

Comment: There is no TryLoadXml on XmlDocument object. You will have to include the LoadXml in a try/catch block to handle exception.

Comment: I know `TryLoadXml` doesn't exist thats why I asked for something *like* it. But I was hoping there was at least some way to do it using something like `XmlReader` to do validation before loading it.

Comment: Empty result is *a valid option* for malformed XML. Please [edit] the post to clarify what is your input and what output you hope to get out of it. (and ideally explain how common "use HtmlAgilityPack" to read not-really-XML is not enough).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I added a code example of what I want to do. I don't want to read not-quite-XML, I want to reject it without an exception if possible.

Comment: None of the classes dealing with XML in the framework have parsing modes that don't throw exceptions, down to the lowest level (`XmlReader`). Unless you have to parse thousands of invalid documents a second, the overhead of the exceptions should not be relevant. You can always write your own wrapper (extension) method that transmutes `XmlException` into a result.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4081472/1752270) thread look helpful?

Comment: @AndrewSilver No, because I don't want to tolerate errors, I just want to manage them without Exceptions because those aren't nice.